# How to choose a FIWARE NGSI-LD context broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-scorpio, fiware-stellio

I need some help to decide which FIWARE context broker (Orion-LD, Scorpio, Stellio) I should choose for a smart city architecture. There is no existing component which uses NGSI-v2.

Is there any other reason why you should choose the Orion-LD context broker besides the fact that it is the only one that supports NGSI-v2?
Is there an advantage that the Orion broker is the main component of FIWARE?

The paper "Open-Source Publish-Subscribe Systems: A Comparative Study" says the scorpio broker is the most complete system overall.

The paper "Enabling Context-Aware Data Analytics in Smart Environments: An Open Source Reference Implementation" says the Orion-LD context broker is the most extended GE.

I also saw the performance comparison where Orion-LD is way faster at small batches of messages and slower than Scorpio and Stellio with larger batches.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, look me up and I'll explain all you need to know. I'm the architect of Orion-LD, and you can find/contact me via the github of Orion-LD. I promise to be 100% objective

Comment: You say "There is no existing component which uses NGSI-v2". Is also correct the dual sentence, i.e. "There is no existing component which uses NGSI-LD"?

Comment: In the existing smart city architecture no component uses NGSI-v2, so NGSI-v2 is not mandatory.

Comment: Is NGSI-LD mandatory? Or neither of them is mandatory and you don't have constrains regarding that?

Comment: Yes NGSI-LD is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Orion-LD is easy to operate, only the service and MongoDB. Scorpio uses Kafka which adds an extra complexity layer, operations-wise. I don't have any reference on Stellio.

Orion-LD supports NGSIv2 as it is a fork of Orion but it is not its main focus. If you are starting fresh, you can adopt directly LD, and you are done.

Comment: Being precise, Orion-LD supports the NGSIv2 API existing when the fork was done in September 2018 if I'm remembering correctly. That's pretty old. The current NGSIv2 API (at the present moment, the one implemented by Orion 3.8.0, releases in January 2023, i.e. more than 4 years after the fork) has strongly evolved. Recent improvement as NGSI patching in custom notifications, flow control or update operators (to mention just a few ones) are not available in the NGSIv2 implemented by Orion-LD. As you say "it [NGSIv2] is not its [Orion-LD] focus".

Comment: @fgalan I wonder if you have already made a decision and how that went?

Comment: @RuslanGonzalez what do you mean? I don't understand you question, sorry...

Comment: @fgalan I was wondering if you have opted for any particular context broker. And if you have any personal preference.

Comment: Yes, I have. My preference is Orion Context Broker, which is the original NGSI broker (existing much before NGSI-LD was ever invented ;). It is mature technology widely used in sound productive scenarios. Its newest version is 3.10.1 and is still evolving. It doesn't support NGSI-LD, but real experience shows that NGSIv2 perfectly covers whichever use case you may need (I would be really interested in knowing about use cases not covered by NGSIv2, honestly).

Comment: @fgalan You're right. Currently, we're also using NGSIv2 and, so far, we haven't encountered any issues with it. I'm glad to hear that there's still activity around Orion and that it's continuously evolving. Our biggest concern is the potential need to switch data formats and, more importantly, the implications of such a change. We're wary of adopting immature technology. Personally, I haven't seen many adopting Scorpio and even fewer using Stellio... that's why we're sticking with the original version for now.